# WordPress - Contact Form

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

I trasfered a Wordpress site from an old hosting provider to another. To do this I performed these steps:

- I download the public_html content from the old provider;
- I exported the database content from the old provider;
- I tried using the WordPress automatic import but it doesn't work (it could not establish the FTP connection with the old provider);
- I installed Wordpress in the new provider;
- I copied the old public_html folder in the new one;
- I imported all the old tables from the previous Database export;
- I corrected the database connection (DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, ...) in the wp-config.php file;

At this point the site seems to work... but not the "Contact Form". In fact, after activate the WordPress debug mode, if I send a message from the site I get this response in my debug.log:

```
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'RevSliderFunctionsWP' not found in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php:91
Stack trace:
#0 /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-settings.php(305): include_once()
#1 /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-config.php(88): require_once('/home/yc32of0z/...')
#2 /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/yc32of0z/...')
#3 /home/yc32of0z/public_html/xmlrpc.php(29): include('/home/yc32of0z/...')
#4 {main}
thrown in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/revslider.php on line 91
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/wp/widgets.php on line 4
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_NAME already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 19
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_USER already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 22
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 25
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_HOST already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 28
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_CHARSET already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 31
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_COLLATE already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 34
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(wp-salt.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(wp-salt.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:34 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'wp-salt.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/wp/widgets.php on line 4
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_NAME already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 19
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_USER already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 22
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 25
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_HOST already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 28
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_CHARSET already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 31
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_COLLATE already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 34
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(wp-salt.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(wp-salt.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:21:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'wp-salt.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/wp/widgets.php on line 4
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_NAME already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 19
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_USER already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 22
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_PASSWORD already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 25
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_HOST already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 28
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_CHARSET already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 31
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Notice:  Constant DB_COLLATE already defined in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 34
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(wp-salt.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(wp-salt.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:22:35 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'wp-salt.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/framework/functions-wordpress.class.php on line 41
[22-Nov-2018 16:23:35 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/yc32of0z/public_html/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/wp/widgets.php on line 4
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like you might be missing the "revslider" plugin. I'd check to see if it's installed and activated on your new site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After your message I check the plugins in my New WordPress Admin Panel but they seem to be ok. I tryed to update them too but the problem still remain.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Revolution Slider plugin has some files missing. Try deleting the Revolution Slider plugin and then installing it again from the wp-admin.

Comment: Thanks to your reply. What I found is that Revolution Slider is a Premium plugin so, I'm not sure but I'm thinking that this is the problem. Can be?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.